# Range copy-paste vba

Tags: vba, excel

The code below is transfering the values from column A to column D. When copied from column A, the values are always pasted on the next row empty in column D.

Is it possible to make this code to copy the values from column A only when new values are inserted? because what it does now, it takes all the values from column A and paste them again in column D.

i.e. Column A: a1 = 2; a2 = 3, a3 = 4 ---> Column D becomes: d1 = 2; d2 = 3; d3 = 4.

now if I insert two other values in column A: a4 = 1; a5 = 2, I want only those two values two be transfered in column D, and not the all numbers again. So column D becomes d1 = 2; d2 = 3; d3 = 4, d4 = 1; d5 = 2.

Thanks in advance!

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet1")
     .Range("a5", .Range("a5").End(xlDown)).Copy
End With

With Sheets("Sheet1")
     .Range("d" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You can use just one `With` block here instead of two as they're both addressing the same Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the requirements:

- Only copy new data
- Has to be copied when user clicks a button

Here's what you could do:

In the Worksheet that the button / data lives on:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet

    Dim newdata As Range
    Set newdata = Application.Intersect(target, sh.Range("A5", "A" & sh.Rows.Count))

    If (Not newdata Is Nothing) Then
        If (CopyDataRange Is Nothing) Then
            Set CopyDataRange = newdata
        Else
            Set CopyDataRange = Application.Union(CopyDataRange, newdata)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In a Module:

```
Option Explicit

Public CopyDataRange As Range

Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If (Not CopyDataRange Is Nothing) Then
        CopyDataRange.Copy CopyDataRange.Offset(0, 3)
        Set CopyDataRange = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```

What this will do is keep track of the new values only (this is what the `Worksheet_Change` event does), then when you click the button, it will copy only the new values to column D. It also resets the static range `CopyDataRange` back to `Nothing` so you don't repeat copying the same data from previous button clicks. Essentially, the button click will flush out the `CopyDataRange` range.

EDIT:

I decided to write a post about this [here](https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/copy-new-data-vba/) to explain it further.

Comment: yes, this is what I want, but it has to be under a button. That is the reason of  not using a worksheet change event...

Comment: @alex2002 I see. That could get a bit complicated. That would mean that when your workbook loads, you need to collect the current state of the worksheet you want to monitor. From there, you would have to keep a `Range` object that holds the addresses of existing values.

Comment: @alex2002 check out the latest version

Comment: I have tried to implement this code for other columns in the same worksheet i.e. copy from _column C_ and paste it in _column F_. At the end, I receive the error that there is a duplication based on **CopyDataRange** when I am trying to run the macro, which is understandable as the macro doesn't know in which column should it look 1st, A or C. Is there any way I can add other columns that need to be pasted in different columns by using the code?  like, when i press the button, the values from col.A goes to col.D while the ones from col.C goes to column D?Thanks

Comment: @alex2002 if you only need to add one more column you could have separate variables to track separate columns like `CopyDataRangeA` and `CopyDataRangeC`. If you end up needing more than this, I would recommend considering a more advanced data structure like a custom type (see https://bettersolutions.com/vba/data-types/user-defined-types.htm)

Comment: back again with a simple question. Is it possible to add in the code to copy the data only as values and not the all format? Thanks

Comment: @alex2002 yes, change `CopyDataRange.Copy CopyDataRange.Offset(0, 3)` into two lines: 1) `CopyDataRange.Copy` and 2) `CopyDataRange.Offset(0, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues`. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

As you guys said that it is a bit complicated, i modified the code and what it does now is to copy everything from the beginning. Not sure if this is the smart solution to use...

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     With Sheets("Creation")
        .Range("a1", .Range("a1").End(xlDown)).Copy End With

With Sheets("Creation")
        .Range("d1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

End With End Sub
```